# Is there alternative for JSchemaPreloadedResolver?

Tags: c#, json, json.net, njsonschema

I am trying to resolve a JSON schema from a URL. I can use `JSchemaPreloadedResolver` from the `Newtonsoft.Json.Schema` library to do this but I must not use this library. Is there any other alternative for this? Perhaps in `NJsonSchema` or any other library?

Comment: https://github.com/RicoSuter/NJsonSchema can work with schemas and is MIT license

Comment: I have actually mentioned that already in my question. I am looking for  functionality similar to JSchemaPreLoadedResolver in other libraries. I couldn't find the exact in NJsonSchema

Comment: https://github.com/RicoSuter/NJsonSchema/blob/master/src/NJsonSchema/JsonReferenceResolver.cs

Comment: thanks, used it and works easy.